# "to fill the emptiness within someone"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word (specifically ONE word) that means "to complete someone" or "to fill the emptiness within someone"?

This word will be a title.

Answer (score 1):

A little more context in which you wish to place the word would be helpful but I suggest *fulfil* may be useful in sentences such as “After they met, he was fulfilled”.

> Fulfil = to satisfy someone or to make someone feel happy
>
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fulfil

American spelling is *fulfill*

Here is a randomly selected example:

> First, to truly understand men and how to make them feel fulfilled in a loving relationship, it is helpful to realize that men don’t just want love—they want to be respected.
>
> [Lifehack](https://www.lifehack.org/329961/20-ways-men-can-feel-fulfilled-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

One of the senses of the word **match**.

It's a metaphor. When we have a pair of socks, for instance, we say each pair matches the other. They can complete only one another.

> If two people who are having a relationship are a good match, they complete each other. e.g. *Theirs is a match made in heaven (they are very suitable to each other)*

[Source: Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/match)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going for:

> [plenum](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/plenum)

As in:

> You are my *plenum*

Definitions:

> a full assembly
> the whole of space regarded as being filled with matter

Comment: _You are my plenum_ Is this example provided by some dictionary? :)

Comment: [Poetic licence](https://www.bing.com/search?q=Poetic+license). Emptiness is a vacuum, and plenum is an antonym of vacuum.

Comment: But doesn't _Plenum_ refer to *the space which is full of matter*, or *the condition of being full*? I don't see how it fits the bill :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered *satiate*?

> having one's appetite completely satisfied ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/satiate))

> To provide (someone) with more than enough. ([American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=satiate))

Related words include *sate, sated, satiety*